# AVFoundation Audio not stopping on mute

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

Hey guys so for some reason when you mute the phone the audio is still coming from the app. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
private func myFunc() {
    // Set up the audio session
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unable to set the audio session because: \(error)")
    }


    guard
        let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "lololol", withExtension: "mp3"),
        let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)

        else { fatalError("Unable to create player") }

    if let aPlayer = audioPlayer {

        if audioPlayer?.isPlaying == false {
            audioPlayer = player

            player.play()
        }

    } else {
            audioPlayer = player
            player.play()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by changing `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`.